# c# accessing class methods in List<List<T>>

Tags: c#

I have a class that I wish to embed in a jagged list.  I have created the list as `List<T>[]` but have been unable to insert or extract data from the list.

In the code below, the line

```
jaggedList[2].AddSomething("this is a string");
```

generates an error:

> "Error CS1061 'List' does not contain a definition for 'AddSomething' and no extension method 'AddSomething' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The line

```
jaggedList[i].Finish();
```

produces a similar error message.

There is also a problem with the `otheFunctions(ref jaggedList[i], i);` line and the compiler error is:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ref ListList.MyList'

but isn't List what jaggesList[I] is?  I suspect that this is my problem but don't understand what exactly it is.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int dynamicallyEstablishedLength = 0;

        dynamicallyEstablishedLength = 4;
        List<MyList>[] jaggedList = new List<MyList>[dynamicallyEstablishedLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < jaggedList.Length; i++)
            jaggedList[i] = new List<MyList>(); //allocate space for each element

        jaggedList[2].AddSomething("this is a string");

        for (int i = 0; i < jaggedList.Length; i++)
            otheFunctions(ref jaggedList[i], i);

        for (int i = 0; i < jaggedList.Length; i++)
            jaggedList[i].Finish();
    }

    void otheFunctions(ref MyList list, int i)
    {
        list.AddSomething("this is string" + i.ToString());
    }
}

public class MyList
{
    private List<string> list;

    public MyList()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddSomething(string line, int trace = 0)
    {
        //do some processing on line
        //then
        list.Add(line);
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        foreach (string s in list)
            Trace.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want `List<MyList> jaggedList = new List<MyList>(dynamicallyEstablishedLength);`, not an array of a list of lists. BTW this looks like a maintenance nightmare, why create this to begin with?

Comment: With regard to error `AddSomething` does not exits: `jaggedList` is an array of `List<T>` (with T being MyList). If you do `jaggedList[i]`, you access one of those possible `List<T>` elements in the array. Now, the type `List<T>` itself does not have a method "AddSomething". You would need to access an element in that `List<T>` object -- which would be a `MyList` object -- on which you could call AddSomething.

Comment: With regard to `otheFunctions` error: Same issue/cause as the first error. `jaggedList[i]` gives you a `List<MyList>` object (not a `MyList` object). But the first argument of otheFunctions has to be of type `MyList`, hence error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is clear, because the instance `List<MyList>[] jaggedList = new List<MyList>...` is of type `List<>` not type `MyList`. so few ways to solve this, ie, create an extension method on the type `List<>`:

```
public static class ListExtensionMethods
{
    ...

    static public void AddSomething<T>(this List<T> list, string line, int trace = 0)
    {
        //do some processing on line
        //then
        list.Add(line);
    }

    static public void Finish<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

or, use the type `MyList` instead of `List<>`:

```
MyList[] jaggedList = new MyList[100];
...
jaggedList[0].AddSomething(...)
```

the second error, is a result of the first error. please search c# extension methods for more info.

Comment: Thanks mad.meesh.  Changing the code to    MyList[] jaggedList = new MyList[dynamicallyEstablishedLength];
   for (int i = 0; i < jaggedList.Length; i++)
    jaggedList[i] = new MyList();     //allocate space for each element solved all of the problems.  I was getting too buried in list of list of ….

Comment: @John glad it worked, please mark the answer as an accepted answer if you so feel inclined :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that in this line `jaggedList[2].AddSomething("this is a string");`,
jaggedList[2] is a List and you cannot access the methods of MyList directly from it.
You can however try something like `jaggedList[2][1].AddSomething("this is a string");`

Answer (score 0):

mad.meesh had the answer.  Changing the code to

```
MyList[] jaggedList = new MyList[dynamicallyEstablishedLength];
for (int i = 0; i < jaggedList.Length; i++)
    jaggedList[i] = new MyList();
```

Solved all of my issues.  Thanks for all of the comments.